# Why is Image not showing in angular home component project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, image

I am working on an angular project but trying to add an image to a table row in the html component . The image is not showing and I have tried many ways to make it work but still can't get it to show . Here is the home.component.html code :

The Images are in a folder named "images" in the project folder under the e2e folder , atop the node_modules folder

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/Larissa.jpg" alt="investor1">
<p>"Trusted and quick profit. I use this website many times and I recommend it."</p>
</td>
<td>
    <img src="images/petroski.jpg" alt="investor2">

    <p>"I feel safe with the knowledge that my  investment is secured and safe with Coin Rush."</p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="images/marie.jpg" alt="investor3">
<p>"Thank you i am very impressed”</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the images folder?

Comment: You have to put it in the public folder.

Comment: The image folder is there under the e2e folder , atop the node_modules folder

Comment: Can you get the image in the browser? I mean, do you have a url so if you put it in the browser, you'll see the image?

Comment: Add the image folder to assets folder, or add the image folder path to assets array in `angular.json` [Read more here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Images are loaded from those folders which are set static or we can say `assets` folder.
If you want to load specific resource, then you must put that resource under assets.

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets"
 ],
```

If you want to create new folder, then provide that folder path under assets in `angular.json`.

And provide relative path starting with your folder.
For example,

```
Your image is under the path src/assets/images/1.jpg
```

Then you need to provide path as

```
<img src="assets/images/1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

e2e folder is not a public folder. It will be used by e2e testing.
You can google it by End to end testing (E2E).
https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-e2e-testing-with-the-angular-cli-and-protractor

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a directory named `assets` and inside this directory you can store all the images required in your project, to use those images you have to provide relative path of images in the `src` attribute of the image tag